# Chrome extension message body manipulation not working

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, gmail

**Problem**:

I am working on a Chrome extension, which shall, on key press of tab, prevent default event and insert 4 space characters.

**My code**: (with unnecessary things omitted and methods doing the thing they should; I don't think I need to give the method definition for `.setText`, etc. which I use below because they *are* correct)

```
value = this.getText();

var cursorPos, // current position of cursor (caret)
    string; // string where content goes starts with four black spaces

// if contenteditable div
if (this.tagName === "DIV") {
    cursorPos = getCaretPosition(this);
}
// normal textbox
else {
    cursorPos = this.selectionStart;
}

var endString = value.substr(cursorPos),
    startString = value.substr(0, cursorPos);

console.log(startString);
console.log(endString);

string = startString + "    " + endString;

this.setText(string);

// 4 => number of whitespace in tab characters
var caretPos = startString.length + 4;

// if contenteditable div
if (this.tagName === "DIV") {
    setCaretPosition(this, caretPos);
}
// normal textbox
else {
    this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd = caretPos;
}
```

It seems to be doing the right thing but still it doesn't work. When I do:

```
aa
 ^tab between two a's
```

I get `a a` (one space) when I should get `a    a` four spaces.

I have seen many solutions (for different problems actually) but none work.

Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this solution took me a lot of time (2 days to figure out), I decided to answer my question to help anyone who might encounter this problem in future. The solution turned out to use a function to detect if I am on a gmail page, and if I am, then replace the spaces with `&nbsp;`s.

```
// returns whether webpage is of gmail or not
function isGmail(){
    return /mail\.google/.test(window.location.href);
}

value = this.getText();

var cursorPos, // current position of cursor (caret)
    string; // string where content goes starts with four black spaces

// if contenteditable div
if (this.tagName === "DIV") {
    cursorPos = getCaretPosition(this);
}
// normal textbox
else {
    cursorPos = this.selectionStart;
}

// gmail case: replace `&nbsp;` with spaces
if (isGmail())
    value = value.replace(/&nbsp;/g, " ");

var endString = value.substr(cursorPos),
    startString = value.substr(0, cursorPos);

console.log(startString);
console.log(endString);

string = startString + "    " + endString;

// gmail case: replace spaces with `&nbsp;`
if (isGmail())
    string = string.replace(/ /g, "&nbsp;");

this.setText(string);

// ... code skipped
```

Thanks for viewing!

Comment: is this the actual question? if so why is it an answer?

Comment: @source.rar No, this is not the question. I have just left this as a footnote for anyone who might want to answer it, but it is not the real question. I made this Q&A with the intent of helping anyone who encounters such a thing in the future.